# Toad and SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, toad

```
where a.system_nr =''''5300'''' and
      a.external_status_cd = '''''''' and
      a.cust_acct_id = b.rel_cust_acct_id and
      b.cust_acct_id = c.cust_acct_id and
      c.cust_acct_id = d.cust_acct_id and
      d.acct_status_cd = ''''OPEN'''' and
      d.time_mnth_gen_id =''''' + @BegDate + ''''' and
      a.cust_acct_id = e.cust_acct_id and
      e.tran_dt >=''''' + @BegDate + ''''' and 
      e.tran_dt<=''''' + @EndDate + ''''' and 
      d.portfolio_cd = ''''HEQ'''' and
      a.time_mnth_gen_id =''''' + @BegDate + ''''' '')'
```

Here is the where condition which is already written and I need to make changes.

Can you please tell me why they are using `'''''+@begdate'''''`? Can i use `'+Bedate'`?
I mean why they are using `'''''` each side?

Comment: Because the column values include single quotes in them?

Comment: I suspect you've deemed the complete statement that constructs the dynamic query too large to include in your question. But it would be much easier to show which pair of quotes encloses what, on the complete version. Still, basically the answer is: it has to do with quoting the quote character (`'`).

Answer (score 0):

Try this in SQL Server:

```
select '''''someval'''''
```

You notice that item gives:

```
''someval''
```

In SQL Server `''` will equate to a single quote character, so the above line is

```
select [open string][single quote][single quote]someval[single quote][single quote][close string]
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the rest of the SQL, my guesses would be:

1. for use in dynamic SQL as `@BegDate` is a variable and you have the statement ending with a single quote
2. the data contains a bunch of single quotes

You should not be able to just `'+BegDate'` because it's a variable and stripping the `@` would cause it to be evaluated as a field.

If you meant to just reduce the number of single quotes, I would imagine the original author put them there for a reason. You can run the query with the original single quotes and again with the reduced single quotes and see if you get the same result set.